# prioritizing a jquery function to override another

Tags: jquery, click, mouseenter, mouseleave

Using jQuery, I am trying to program 2 different kinds of feedback within search menu buttons. The issue is that the 2 require conflicting code:

First, show that the red buttons are "clickable" by changing one to a different color (blue) when the mouse enters it, and then changing it back to the original color (red) when the mouse leaves it:

```
$('.buttons').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
$('.buttons').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Second, show that a certain button is "clicked" by changing the button to a 3rd color (yellow). I want the button to remain yellow until a new/different button is clicked. When that happens, I want the newly clicked button to change to yellow, and all other buttons to revert back to the original color (red).

```
$(".buttons").click(function() {
$(".buttons").css("background-color", "red");
$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

This all works nicely until the mouse leaves the clicked button to move to another. When this happens, mouseleave changes the yellow button back to red.

Is there a way to prioritize jQuery commands? Is there another function I should use instead? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't do this with CSS and just have the click event add a class to change the color yellow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use class instead of `.css()` function. It is much simpler. Use something like this :

```
$('.buttons').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
}).on('click', function(){
    $('.buttons').removeClass('click').filter(this).addClass('click');
})
```

With those css :

```
.buttons{
    background-color : red;
}

/*
Could also be .buttons:hover an then remove the JS
Much more efficient
*/
.buttons.hover{
    background-color : blue;
}

.buttons.click{
    background-color : yellow;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Re9bj/12/

Comment: Thanks for the help! The drawback to this is the clicked button remains yellow even when a new button is clicked. I would like only the most recently clicked button to stay yellow.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use css classes to achieve this.

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nzp8S/)**

**CSS:**

```
.buttons {
    background-color: red;
}
.buttons:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
.clicked {
 background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var $buttons = $('.buttons')
$buttons.click(function () {
  $buttons.removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<button class='buttons'>Button 1 </button>
<button class='buttons'>Button 2 </button>
<button class='buttons'>Button 3 </button>
<button class='buttons'>Button 4 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

give the clicked button an id and then check that id on mouseleave

heres a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudigerkidd/6H7kZ/)

```
$('.buttons').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
$('.buttons').mouseleave(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "clicked" ) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    } else {
       $(this).css("background-color", "red"); 
    }
});

$(".buttons").click(function() {
    $(".buttons").css("background-color", "red");
    $(".buttons").attr("id","");
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    $(this).attr("id","clicked");
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I am happy to learn more about what is possible with jQuery. However, I think I'm going to change to CSS to be more efficient, thanks to the comments from others.

Comment: @user3064186 no worries :)